# Can these models be represented in EF7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use some classes from another assembly in my own project as entities that I can persist using EF7, rather than writing a series of very similar classes that are more database-friendly.

Simplified versions look like this:

```
interface IMediaFile
{
    string Uri { get; }
    string Title { get; set; }
}
class CMediaFile : IMediaFile
{
    public CMediaFile() { }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

//The following types are in my project and have full control over.
interface IPlaylistEntry
{
    IMediaFile MediaFile { get; }
}
class CPlaylistEntry<T> : IPlaylistEntry where T : IMediaFile
{
    public CPlaylistEntry() { }
    public T MediaFile { get; set; }
}
```

There are multiple implementations of IMediaFile, I am showing only one.  My PlaylistEntry class takes a generic argument to enable different traits for those various implementations, and I just work with the IPlaylistEntry.

So I've started to model it like so:

```
var mediaFile = _modelBuilder.Entity<CMediaFile>();
mediaFile.Key(e => e.Uri);
mediaFile.Index(e => e.Uri);
mediaFile.Property(e => e.Title).MaxLength(256).Required();

var mediaFilePlaylistEntry = _modelBuilder.Entity<CPlaylistEntry<CMediaFile>>();
mediaFilePlaylistEntry.Key(e => e.MediaFile);
mediaFilePlaylistEntry.Reference(e => e.MediaFile).InverseReference();
```

As a simple test, I ignore the CPlaylistEntry<> and just do:

```
dbContext.Set<CMediaFile>().Add(new CMediaFile() { Uri = "irrelevant", Title = "" });
dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

This throws:

> NotSupportedException: The 'MediaFile' on entity type 'CPlaylistEntry' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'CMediaFile'.  Either set a value for the property before adding the entity or configure a value generator for properties of type 'CMediaFile'`

I don't even understand this exception, and I don't see why CPlaylistEntry is appearing when I'm only trying to store a CMediaFile entity.  I'm guessing this is related to my model definition - specifically defining the primary key of the CPlaylistEntry as not a simple type, but a complex type - another entity.  However I would expect EF to be smart enough to work out that it all boils down to a string Uri, because that complex type has its own primary key declared already, and I have declared the property as a foreign key to that type.

Is it possible to model these classes in EF without radically redesigning them to look closer to what corresponding database tables might be?  I've worked with EF6 database-first in the past, so this is my first attempt into a code-first pattern, and I'm really hoping that I can isolate the mess that a database might look like to just my model definition, and keep "clean" classes that I interact with in .NET.

If more explanation of these types and their relationship is required, just ask - I'm attempting to keep this brief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Doubt this is currently supported (unsure if it eventually will or not).| I've tried to recreate your model with slight changes and when trying to create the database I get:</s>

> System.NotSupportedException: The property 'PlaylistEntry`1MediaFile'
>   cannot be mapped because it is of type 'MediaFile' which is currently
>   not supported.

**Update 1**

I think that the fact that you are putting MediaFile as a key is creating problems. I've done a few changes to your model. I hope this will not break anything negative on your end:

```
public interface IPlaylistEntry<T>
    where T : IMediaFile
{
    T MediaFile { get; set; }
}

public class PlaylistEntry<T> : IPlaylistEntry<T>
    where T : IMediaFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlaylistInfo { get; set; } //added for testing purposes
    public T MediaFile { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
     builder.ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();

     builder.Entity<MediaFile>().ForRelational().Table("MediaFiles");
     builder.Entity<MediaFile>().Key(e => e.Uri);
     builder.Entity<MediaFile>().Index(e => e.Uri);
     builder.Entity<MediaFile>().Property(e => e.Title).MaxLength(256).Required();

     builder.Entity<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().ForRelational().Table("MediaFileEntries");
     builder.Entity<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Key(e => e.Id);
     builder.Entity<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Reference(e => e.MediaFile).InverseReference();
 }
```

Usage:

```
  var mediaFile = new MediaFile() {Uri = "irrelevant", Title = ""};
  context.Set<MediaFile>().Add(mediaFile);
  context.SaveChanges();

  context.Set<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Add(new PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>
  {
      MediaFile = mediaFile,
      PlaylistInfo = "test"
  });

  context.SaveChanges();
```

This works and saves the correct data to the database.

You can retrieve the data using:

```
  var playlistEntryFromDb = context.Set<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>()
         .Include(plemf => plemf.MediaFile).ToList();
```

**Update 2**

Since you do not want to have an identity as key, you can add a Uri property to your playlistentry class that will be used for the relationship between PlaylistEntry and MediaFile.

```
public class PlaylistEntry<T> : IPlaylistEntry<T>
    where T : IMediaFile
{
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string PlaylistInfo { get; set; }
    public T MediaFile { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what the mapping in this case would look like:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MediaFile>().ForRelational().Table("MediaFiles");
        builder.Entity<MediaFile>().Key(e => e.Uri);
        builder.Entity<MediaFile>().Index(e => e.Uri);
        builder.Entity<MediaFile>().Property(e => e.Title).MaxLength(256).Required();

        builder.Entity<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().ForRelational().Table("MediaFileEntries");
        builder.Entity<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Key(e => e.Uri);
        builder.Entity<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Reference(e => e.MediaFile).InverseReference().ForeignKey<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>(e => e.Uri);
    }
```

Usage to insert data stays the same:

```
 var mediaFile = new MediaFile() { Uri = "irrelevant", Title = "" };
 context.Set<MediaFile>().Add(mediaFile);
 context.SaveChanges();

 context.Set<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Add(new PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>
 {
     MediaFile = mediaFile,
     PlaylistInfo = "test"
 });

 context.SaveChanges();
```

This code above will put "irrelevant" in the PlaylistEntry Uri property since it is used as the foreign key.

And to retrieve data:

```
    var mediaFiles = context.Set<PlaylistEntry<MediaFile>>().Include(x => x.MediaFile).ToList();
```

The join will occur on the Uri field in both tables.

Comment: Perhaps I'm hoping a bit too much for EF7 (;  Thanks for trying.

Comment: @SamNelson Actually now that I'm thinking about it, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity uses this type of mapping with generics and EF plays nice with it. I'll try to dig further.

Comment: not exactly the answer I wanted to see, since the identity Id property is completely meaningless to my .NET code, and effectively doubles up on the purpose the key (Uri property) already serves.  But I guess this is as good as it gets right now - your research is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: I made the suggestion to add this here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/8102202-support-another-entity-as-a-key

Comment: @SamNelson See update #2. I may have misunderstood something initially. I hope this updated code works for your needs.

Comment: yeah I deduced this from your first update, and of course it works, thanks.  I was just hoping not to let the database schema leak into my .NET classes.  In .NET, the PlaylistEntry already has a Uri - it's within its MediaFile property.  Rather than having to duplicate that property into the PlaylistEntry class side-by-side with the MediaFile property that already contains it, I wanted EF to just figure that out from the keys.  That's what my suggestion on UserVoice requests.